# How can I know which VisualState of control already defined in WPF's XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, visualstates

How can I know which VisualState of control already defined in XAML?

For example, WPF Button control has 2 VisualStateGroups by default. They are "CommonStates" and "FocusStates". The "CommonStates" contains 4 VisualState: "Normal", "MouseOver", "Pressed", "Disabled". These states already have default handlers so when the mouse over or pressed, Button's VisualState changes corresponding.
Thank you for reading!

Comment: Have you know about Blend ?? Use it 

Comment: This? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065118/how-do-i-programmatically-get-the-current-visual-state-of-a-wpf-frameworkelement?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

The wpf designer of visual studio has an "edit template" function. You can use that to veiw any control's default template. You can do that by follow the steps:

1. Add the control to designer correctly.
2. Right click the control -> Edit Template -> Edit a Copy.

If you can't do that, you still can get templates of standard wpf controls from msdn https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/control-styles-and-templates

Answer (score 0):

I just have found the list of VisualState which is built-in with Button control right here: [Button VisualStates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/button-styles-and-templates#button-states)

You can also find the list for other control there.